# Cordova event DeviceReady don't work on all pages

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-build

Well i have multiple page

In cordova, when it start, this show first `index.html`and trigger `deviceready` event on javascript, and when i clicked on link like to `search.html`, the WebView change and load the `search.html` but dont trigger `deviceready` javascript event.

> So, right now i use `onload` in another pages because i think
>   `deviceready` event only trigger when the App is ready to work(only
>   one time at the start).

Example(index.html, this work well):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        ...
        <script>
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
                console.log('Device is Ready!!');
            }, false);
        </script>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="search.html">Go to search</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Example( XYZ.html, this don't because never trigger `deviceready`):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        ...
        <script>
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
                console.log('Device is Ready!!');
            }, false);
        </script>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="index.html">Go to Index</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Example of file structure:

```
+ www/
    - .
    - ..
    + js/
        - jquery.min.js
        - bootstrap.min.js
    + css/
        - bootstrap.min.css
    + img/
        - logo.png
        - default.png
        + icons/
            - alert.png
            - danger.png
            - important.png
    - icon.png
    - index.html
    - searh.html
    - favorites.html
    - contacts.html
    - configuration.html
    - about.html
```

Config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.cordovacrosswalk.app" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>CordovaAndCrosswalkApp</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <preference name="xwalkVersion" value="15+" />
    <preference name="xwalkCommandLine" value="--disable-pull-to-refresh-effect" />
    <preference name="xwalkMode" value="embedded" />
    <preference name="xwalkMultipleApk" value="true" />
</widget>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you applying the [whitelist system](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-whitelist)? did you read the [guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide/appdev/whitelist/index.html)? This *whitelist* worksheet should help. [HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md)

Comment: Yes, i apply whitelist

Comment: Since you only answer one (1) question, I will take your answer as *"not really"*. Please post your `config.xml`, so I can take a look at it. My impression is you are still a beginner. (make a liar out of me please)

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 i post the `config.xml` and yes, i'm beginner.

Comment: Damm. thanks for posting. Give me about 20 minutes.

Comment: Are you linking the cordova.js in all the .html files?

Comment: Yes, in all documents...

Comment: @OlafErlandsen  Is your issue solved?

Comment: No... I trying removing Crosswalk and work, but i need Crosswalk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@olaf,
you need to [read the documentation](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/index.html) and blogs [*Phonegap Build*](http://phonegap.com/blog/phonegap-build/) and [*Cordova*](https://cordova.apache.org/blog/). Cordova/Phonegap is a mess. NOTE: Cordova is the base for *many* [hybrid platforms](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/hybrid-frameworks.md), including *Phonegap,Phonegap Build, Ionic, Sencha Touch, etc, et al.*

**These FAQs should also help.**

- [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)
- [HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md)
- [Core Plugins Setup](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/plugins-core-setup.md).

### Your Fixes

1. replacement `config.xml`
2. addition to your `index.html`
3. About your confusion with `onload()` and `deviceready`.
   READ [4. In the code, did not listen for the 'deviceready' event.](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#004) IN [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

Just to be clear on this point. `deviceready` waits until things are load. So in theory, it is waiting for `onload` to complete. I can verify this. I just finished a [new boilerplate](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/Phonegap--Generic-Boilerplate7) for the latest version (cli-5.2.0) of *Phonegap Build*.

The load order is *Splash screen* -> `onload()` -> `ondeviceready()` -> *splash screen hide()*.

**UPDATE:** One last thing. I have several programs that work with multiple pages, so I know most of the gotchas

### Best of Luck

#### 1. replacement `config.xml`

**NOTE YOUR APP IS NOW INSECURE. IT IS UP TO YOU TO SECURE YOUR APP.**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!-- your header is off. READ http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_basics.md.html#The%20Basics -->
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = "com.cordovacrosswalk.app" 
    version   = "0.0.1"
    versionCode = "10"> <!-- versionCode is optional and Android only -->

    <name>CordovaAndCrosswalkApp</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>

    <!-- ONLY needed for IDE/SDK -->
    <!-- <content src="index.html" /> -->

    <!-- Tool Set Version -->        
    <!-- <preference name='phonegap-version' value='3.7.0' /> --> <!-- turns off required whitelist -->
    <!-- <preference name='phonegap-version' value='cli-5.2.0' /> -->

    <!-- Target Platforms -->
    <platform name="android" />
    <platform name="ios" />
    <platform name="windows" />

    <!-- You'll very likely need this on different platform. So you can tell them apart -->
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" version="1.0.1" />

    <!-- WHITELIST * WHITELIST * WHITELIST -->
    <!-- https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md -->
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="1.1.0" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <access origin="*" /> <!-- Required for iOS9 -->

    <plugin name='org.crosswalk.engine' version='1.3.0' source='pgb' />
    <preference name="xwalkVersion" value="15+" />
    <preference name="xwalkCommandLine" value="--disable-pull-to-refresh-effect" />
    <preference name="xwalkMode" value="embedded" />
    <preference name="xwalkMultipleApk" value="true" />
</widget>
```

#### 2. addition to your `index.html`

**NOTE YOUR APP IS NOW INSECURE. IT IS UP TO YOU TO SECURE YOUR APP.**

Add to the top of every HTML file.
READ [HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md) The section on `CSP`

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
         content="default-src *; 
                  style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; 
                  script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
```